# MySQL view disappears

Tags: mysql, view

I made a strange observation. Yesterday at round about 2 pm, I deleted a field in a table which is part of a mysql VIEW. After I deleted it in the table, the VIEW still worked normally.

For what every reason the VIEW disappeared and was deleted at 11:50 pm in the evening. Does anybody have an explanation for that? Is there maybe some kind of crontab running at this time? I am helpless.
After I realized that the VIEW was missing, I created it again and everything worked fine again.

Thank you for help in advance,

Freddy